# Session Variables for Counting Login attempts

Tags: php, authentication, yii, session-variables

I am trying to implement a login scheme where I keep a count on the number of attempts the user tries , this is for security reasons . My code is :

```
{
    ob_start();
    $_SESSION['attempts'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['sleep'] = 0;
    $_SESSION['ip']=$this->get_ip_address() ;
    $login = new User('login');  
    // renders the view file 'protected/views/site/index.php'
    // using the default layout 'protected/views/layouts/main.php'

    if(isset($_POST['yt0']))
    {   
            $login->Username = ($_POST['User']['Username']);
            $salt = $login->getSaltByUsername($login->Username) ;
            $login->SecretCode = $this->hasher($login->Username,($_POST['User']['SecretCode']),$salt);
            var_dump($_SESSION)  ;  /*First Dump , gives all session variables correctly*/
            echo $_SESSION['attempts'] ;
            Yii::app()->user->setState('attempts', $_SESSION['attempts']++); 

            var_dump($_SESSION)  ;
```

I am getting the PHP Notice : "Undefined index: attempts "

However in the first dump as well as the echo i am getting the correct number of attempts . 
What am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: Code that you are showing is so limited that it is hard to know what it might be... what does it say if you change the setState('attempts', to something else? Change it to "tries" instead? Still same error?

Comment: Same error , changed it to 'tries' .

Comment: I would suggest using a cookie rather than a session, for example: if you want to display a captcha after n amount of login attempts, if using a session the user could simply close the browser to close the session, and open the page again and attempt to login without the captcha displaying.

Comment: I am actually planning on introducing sleep based on number of attempts and user's ip address . This would safeguard against a Brute force attack and also DOS as delay is ip and number of attempts based .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `CHttpSession` instead of `$_SESSION`

```
$session=new CHttpSession;
$session->open();

$session['attempts'] = 0;
$session['sleep'] = 0;
$session['ip']=$this->get_ip_address();
```

I've never used `$_SESSION` in any of my Yii projects.